# How to access to an object data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object and want to access to some data but I have an error.

This is the object:

`list = [{"id"=>0,"title"=>"Purple Rain"}, {"id"=>1,"title"=>"Life is a flower"},]`

With binding.pry, i tried to access to the title of the first object by:

`list.first.title`

Can you tell me why it doesn't work? If i do "list.first", it will show the first object without any problem but when i want to access to only one data, i got this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for #<Hash:0x...

Thanks for your help

Comment: If it's a hash then you can use `[]` (`list.first["title"]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash` doesn't have dot syntax.  OpenStructs do.  If you want to use dot syntax, then you can convert to `openstruct` if you want.  But using what Sebastian suggested is fine.

```
list
# => [{"id"=>0, "title"=>"Purple Rain"}, {"id"=>1, "title"=>"Life is a flower"}]
list.first["title"]
# => "Purple Rain"
require 'ostruct'
# => true
obj = OpenStruct.new(list.first)
# => #<OpenStruct id=0, title="Purple Rain">
obj.title
# => "Purple Rain"
```